# fabric.js arrow snapped to grid

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've adapted some code to snap a line to a grid using Fabric.js, as in the code below. What I want is for it to instead be an arrow. I can't seem to get the arrowhead (triangle) to move properly. I kept breaking the code by trying to add a triangle as the arrowhead, so I removed all code attempting to add it. Please help me add the arrowhead, thank you!!

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var grid = 50;
for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }));
  canvas.add(new fabric.Line([ 0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], { stroke: '#ccc', selectable: false }))
}

var line, isDown;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
  canvas.remove(line);
  isDown = true;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  var points = [ Math.round(pointer.x / grid) * grid, Math.round(pointer.y / grid) * grid, pointer.x, pointer.y ];
  line = new fabric.Line(points, {
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center'
  });
  canvas.add(line);
  
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  line.set({ x2: pointer.x, y2: pointer.y });
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
  isDown = false;
  line.set({ x2: Math.round(pointer.x/ grid) * grid, y2: Math.round(pointer.y/ grid) * grid });
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: You need to add the code that you used to try to create the arrow head, explain any errors. At StackOverflow, we prefer to fix existing problems instead of giving out brand new solutions. We want you to understand what was wrong with your previous attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got 'em! For me, the trick was defining the center of the triangle following the method in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ug2gskj1/

```
    left: line.get('x1') + deltaX;
    top: line.get('y1') + deltaY;
```

where

```
    centerX = (line.x1 + line.x2) / 2;
    centerY = (line.y1 + line.y2) / 2;
    deltaX = line.left - centerX;
    deltaY = line.top - centerY;
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    selection: false
  });
  var grid = 50;
  for (var i = 0; i < (600 / grid); i++) {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([i * grid, 0, i * grid, 600], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
    }));
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, i * grid, 600, i * grid], {
      stroke: '#ccc',
      selectable: false
    }))
  }

  var line, triangle, isDown;

  function calcArrowAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var angle = 0,
      x, y;

    x = (x2 - x1);
    y = (y2 - y1);

    if (x === 0) {
      angle = (y === 0) ? 0 : (y > 0) ? Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI * 3 / 2;
    } else if (y === 0) {
      angle = (x > 0) ? 0 : Math.PI;
    } else {
      angle = (x < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + Math.PI : (y < 0) ? Math.atan(y / x) + (2 * Math.PI) : Math.atan(y / x);
    }

    return (angle * 180 / Math.PI + 90);
  }

  canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o) {
    canvas.remove(line, triangle);
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    var points = [Math.round(pointer.x / grid) * grid, Math.round(pointer.y / grid) * grid, pointer.x, pointer.y];
    line = new fabric.Line(points, {
      strokeWidth: 5,
      fill: 'red',
      stroke: 'red',
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center'
    });

    centerX = (line.x1 + line.x2) / 2;
    centerY = (line.y1 + line.y2) / 2;
    deltaX = line.left - centerX;
    deltaY = line.top - centerY;

    triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
      left: line.get('x1') + deltaX,
      top: line.get('y1') + deltaY,
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
      hasBorders: false,
      hasControls: false,
      lockScalingX: true,
      lockScalingY: true,
      lockRotation: true,
      pointType: 'arrow_start',
      angle: -45,
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      fill: 'red'
    });

    canvas.add(line, triangle);

  });

  canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o) {
    //function angle(x1,y1,x2,y2){angle=Math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))*180/Math.PI+90; return angle;}

    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    line.set({
      x2: pointer.x,
      y2: pointer.y
    });
    triangle.set({
      'left': pointer.x + deltaX,
      'top': pointer.y + deltaY,
      'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

  canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o) {
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    isDown = false;
    snappedxCoordinate = Math.round(pointer.x / grid) * grid;
    snappedyCoordinate = Math.round(pointer.y / grid) * grid;
    snappedxCoordinateArrowhead = Math.round((pointer.x + deltaX) / grid) * grid;
    snappedyCoordinateArrowhead = Math.round((pointer.y + deltaY) / grid) * grid;

    line.set({
      x2: snappedxCoordinate,
      y2: snappedyCoordinate
    });
    triangle.set({
      'left': snappedxCoordinateArrowhead,
      'top': snappedyCoordinateArrowhead,
      'angle': calcArrowAngle(line.x1, line.y1, line.x2, line.y2)
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```